# Diagonalizable matrix is symmetric with respect to a certain inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be diagonalizable, then there is and symmetric possitive definite matrix $C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A$ is symmetric w.r.t $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_C$, where $\langle x,y\rangle_C = \langle Cx,y\rangle$.

I have no idea to find $C$. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is your matrix diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$ or over $\mathbb C$? Symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues.

Comment: Over R. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{B} = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Define an inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by letting $(v_i, v_j) := \delta_{ij}$ and extending bilinearly. With respect to the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$, we have

$$ (Av_i, v_j) = (\lambda_i v_i, v_j) = \lambda_i (v_i, v_j) = \lambda_i \delta_{ij} = \lambda_j \delta_{ij} = (v_i, \lambda_j v_j) = (v_i, Av_j) $$

so $A$ (or more precisely, the linear map $T_A \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ associated to $A$, given by $T_A(v) = Av$) is symmetric.

Finally, show that given any inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a positive definite matrix $C$ such that

$$ (v, w) = \left< Cv, w \right> \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n $$

where $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you give me a hint on finding matrix C. I have no idea what is it look like.

Comment: Plugging in the standard basis $e_i$, we have $(e_i, e_j) = \left<Ce_i, e_j \right> = e_i^T C^T e_j = (C^T)_{ij} = C_{ji}$ so the $ij$-th entry of $C$ is $(e_i, e_j)$. Since $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is symmetric, we have $C_{ji} = C_{ij}$. Since $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is positive definite, the matrix $C$ will be positive definite.